# Define text size in R relative to plot window

Tags: r, plot

When I am plotting with R I find that text re adjust on my plots if I maximize plotted window. Y question is:
What can I do with text() to have a fixed font size relative to the plot window size?

```
quartz(7,7) #Use window(7,7) for other windows and Linux
plot( 0,  xlim = c(0,10), ylim = c(0,10), ylab = '', xlab = '')
text(5,5, 'This is an example for Stackexchange. \n
            How can i chose a font size that is relative to the window\'s size?')

quartz(12,12) #Use window(12,12) for other windows and Linux
plot( 0,  xlim = c(0,10), ylim = c(0,10), ylab = '', xlab = '')
text(5,5, 'This is an example for Stackexchange. \n
            How can i chose a font size that is relative to the window\'s size?')
```

The images show what I mean

[image: Smaller window][image: Larger window]

I have tried using cex parameter but it changes absolute value of font size (not relative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked for a 7 inch by 7 inch plot, and got text for that.  Then you asked for a 12 inch by 12 inch plot, but apparently it wouldn't fit in your window, and you got something smaller, then you resized it again to show us.  In both cases you asked for 12 point text (the default).

If you want your text sized proportionally to the window, then you should ask for that.  For example, if you are happy with the first plot and want the same size in the second, try

```
quartz(12, 12, pointsize = 12*(12/7))
```

where `12*(12/7)` rescales the default 12 points by the ratio of the window size you asked for to the previous one.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to make plot  scalable as if they were a pdf? Because I do not use quartz in general I just plot and let Rstudio show me my plot on the bottom right.

Comment: You can use the `pdf()` device, but it won't display automatically.  The device used by RStudio is a custom one produced by them called `RStudioGD`.  I don't know if it is documented anywhere; an old post suggested this worked, `? tools:rstudio:RStudioGD`, but it didn't work for me.  So I don't know if there's an option like you are asking for, but I doubt it, since the other standard devices don't really support that.